# How to execute functions when user closes browser/tab in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, event-handling

I've tried researching this to death but I'm struggling finding a solution that works. I need two methods from two different services to execute on browser/tab close.

I've tried fetch API, which worked great for chrome but couldn't get it to work for IE.
I've tried a while loop like the following:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
onBeforeUnload(): void {
    var sessionEnded = false;
this.userSessionService.EndSession(this.userSessionId).then(res => sessionEnded = res);;
while (sessionEnded == false) {
  console.log('session not ended');
}
  }
```

That worked great for chrome but I couldn't close the IE browser.

Is there anything else out there that I've missed?

Is there possibly a way that a new tab opens to execute the functions then closes on completion?

Comment: Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge?  Because Internet Explorer does not support arrow functions.

Comment: Use a normal function declaration.

Comment: Does it go though your method? What can you see in the console?

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
async onBeforeUnload(): void {
    var sessionEnded = false;
    await sessionEnded = this.userSessionService.EndSession(this.userSessionId);
    while (sessionEnded == false) {
      console.log('session not ended');
    }
  }
```